# Cannot get output Javascript to html correctly

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have tried several methods to make this print randomly inside an html paragraph but it's not working correctly.
Can someone please help me fix the problem?

```
var randomPicker = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5);
var quotesArray = [];

function Quotes(quote, author) {
    this.quote = quote;
    this.author = author;  
}

quotesArray[0] = new Quotes("Great minds discuss ideas; average minds discuss events; small minds discuss people.", "Eleanor Roosevelt");
quotesArray[1] = new Quotes("To be yourself in a world that is constantly trying to make you something else is the greatest accomplishment.", "Ralph Waldo Emerson");
quotesArray[2] = new Quotes("Great things are done by a series of small things brought together.", "Vincent Van Gogh");
quotesArray[3] = new Quotes("Some are born great, some achieve greatness, and some have greatness thrust upon them.", "William Shakespeare");
quotesArray[4] = new Quotes("A tiger does not shout its tigritude, it acts.", "Wole Soyinka");
quotesArray[5] = new Quotes("Thinking start with a problem and ends in a solution.", "Dr. Edward de Bono");


var rand = quotesArray[randomPicker];

function printQuote(){
for (var q in rand){

console.log(rand[q]); //works well but

//this
// document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML = rand[q];
//not working...
    }
}
//this also not working...
document.getElementById("msg").innerHTHL = printQuote();
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can we see your HTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it didn't work was that the elements of your `quotesArray` were not strings but rather objects themselves. You need to access the properties inside these objects to get to the strings.

```js
var randomPicker = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5);
var quotesArray = [];

function Quotes(quote, author) {
    this.quote = quote;
    this.author = author;  
}

quotesArray[0] = new Quotes("Great minds discuss ideas; average minds discuss events; small minds discuss people.", "Eleanor Roosevelt");
quotesArray[1] = new Quotes("To be yourself in a world that is constantly trying to make you something else is the greatest accomplishment.", "Ralph Waldo Emerson");
quotesArray[2] = new Quotes("Great things are done by a series of small things brought together.", "Vincent Van Gogh");
quotesArray[3] = new Quotes("Some are born great, some achieve greatness, and some have greatness thrust upon them.", "William Shakespeare");
quotesArray[4] = new Quotes("A tiger does not shout its tigritude, it acts.", "Wole Soyinka");
quotesArray[5] = new Quotes("Thinking start with a problem and ends in a solution.", "Dr. Edward de Bono");


var rand = quotesArray[randomPicker];

function printQuote() {
    document.getElementById("quote").innerHTML = rand.quote;
    document.getElementById("author").innerHTML = rand.author;
}

printQuote();
```

```html
<p id="quote"></p>
<p id="author"></p>
```

Edit: When creating a new object in JavaScript, it is probably a better idea to use singular names for the object name, instead of plural.

`function Quotes` should be `function Quote`. Likewise, `new Quotes` should be `new Quote`.

This is just a convention.